# gensim LdaModel - How to reduce the number of words in each topic?

Tags: natural-language, unsupervised-learning, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm trying to get more sparse topics (Less overlaps between different topics).

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html

I know it should be determined by the alpha parameter.

I've tried different values of the alpha parameter: ['auto', 'symmetric', 'asymmetric', [0.01]*topic_num, [0.001]*topic_num, [0.00001]*topic_num, etc], also experiment with the 'eta' and 'decay' parameters:

(From the docs):

```
alpha ({numpy.ndarray, str}, optional) –
Can be set to an 1D array of length equal to the number of expected topics that expresses our a-priori belief for the each topics’ probability. Alternatively default prior selecting strategies can be employed by supplying a string:

’asymmetric’: Uses a fixed normalized asymmetric prior of 1.0 / topicno.
’auto’: Learns an asymmetric prior from the corpus (not available if distributed==True).
eta ({float, np.array, str}, optional) –
A-priori belief on word probability, this can be:

scalar for a symmetric prior over topic/word probability,
vector of length num_words to denote an asymmetric user defined probability for each word,
matrix of shape (num_topics, num_words) to assign a probability for each word-topic combination,
the string ‘auto’ to learn the asymmetric prior from the data.
decay (float, optional) – A number between (0.5, 1] to weight what percentage of the previous lambda value is forgotten when each new document is examined. Corresponds to Kappa from Matthew D. Hoffman, David M. Blei, Francis Bach: “Online Learning for Latent Dirichlet Allocation NIPS‘10”.
```

None of these methods gave me sparser topics.

What am I missing? 
How can I get topics with fewer words per topic?

Thanks

EDIT: Experiments with ETA don't work:
It's not changing anything. 
I've done a lot of experiments: 
Baseline: Without mentioning eta (Default) - Got 10 words for each topic, alpha='auto'.

Experiments:
 1. eta=0.01, alpha='asymmetric'
 2. eta=0.00001, alpha='asymmetric'
 3. eta=0.0001, (Without mentioning alpha)
 4. eta=[0.01]*num_words, (Without mentioning alpha)
 5. eta=[0.0001]*num_words, (Without mentioning alpha)
 6. eta=[[0.001 for _ in range(6645)] for _ in range(20)], (Without mentioning alpha)
 7. eta=[[0.000001 for _ in range(6645)] for _ in range(20)] (Without mentioning alpha)
 8. eta=0.01, alpha='symmetric'
 9. eta=0.00001, alpha='symmetric'

All give me 10 words per topic (20 topics)

Answer (score 5):

$\alpha$ is the hyper-parameter for the mixing proportions. The smaller the $\alpha$ the more focused your **documents** will be (they will strongly focus on small number of topics). Btw, it is generally better to allow for an asymmetric $\alpha$.

You want to reduce the other hyper-parameter, $\eta$. The same thing, the smaller the hyper-parameter, the more "focused" the topics will be (comes from the properties of the Dirichlet distribution).

Note however that a topic is not a set of words. It's a distribution over the **whole** vocabulary. Your topic will always be the same length as the size of your vocabulary, and by design all words will have non-zero probability (because of the prior). It's just that if you choose a small $\eta$ most of the probabilities will be extremely small, and most of the probability mass will be contained in relatively few words.

Comment: You can change the number of words that gensim prints (i.e. you can just ask for $n$ most prominent words for each topic), or you can tell gensim that below some threshold you want it to treat probabilities as equal to 0 (for topic distributions you do that by changing the minimum_phi_value parameter) - but I'm not sure it has an impact on estimation.

Comment: I don't see that it gives fewer words per topic. 
I've tried a lot of experiments with eta (see Edit of the post) 
and it gives me the same number of words (10) in each topic.

Comment: Just to be clear - the number of words is always your full vocabulary. It's just that some words will have a very, very small probability (that you ignore based on a threshold).

Comment: But when you're printing topics you also have to choose how many words you want to print (you rarely want all of them). You do that with the `topn` argument.

Comment: But that only changes how many words you see, not how many there are actually in the topic...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`print_topics(num_topics=20, num_words=10)`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.print_topics) to limit the number of topics displayed as well as the number of words. If you simply use `model.print_topics()` there will be always exactly 10 words printed per topic because it is the default value.
You can set `model.print_topics(num_topics=-1)` to print all topics ordered by the relevance of the learned topic. Furthermore, you can set `model.print_topics(num_words=5)` to show fewer words to describe the topic. However, this behavior is completely independent of the settings you tried out which were explained by [@yassem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/161333/yassem).